# How to customize WindowsXPStyle in Qt?

Tags: qt

How to customize WindowsXPStyle in [Qt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28toolkit%29)?

I would like to display the menus and menu items as per the MS Office 2003 style in Qt.

Answer (score 5):

In Qt you can derive from default style classes. You can find the explanation at http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qstyle.html#creating-a-custom-style

Answer (score 2):

Inherit from QWindowsxp style and override DrawControl as per you requirement.

Comment: I am also having same question. Let me know any resolution